# An apparent contradiction in the definition of density matrix

Tags: quantum-information, entropy, quantum-entanglement, density-operator, information

Let $A$ and $B$ be two subsystems of the system AB which is in a pure or isolated bipartite state and $$|\psi_{AB}\rangle=\sum_{i}\sqrt{p_i}|\psi^{i}_{AB}\rangle$$, then by definition
\begin{equation}
  \tag{1}
  \rho_{AB}=\sum_{i}p_i|\psi^{i}_{AB}\rangle\langle \psi^i_{AB}|
  \label{eqn:Definition}
\end{equation}
Here $|\psi^{i}_{AB}\rangle=|\psi^{i}_{A}\rangle\otimes|\psi^{i}_{B}\rangle$.

But since $|\psi_{AB}\rangle$ is a pure state (since it can be written as bra-ket state) we can also say that
\begin{align*} 
\rho_{AB}=|\psi_{AB}\rangle\langle\psi_{AB}|&=(\sum_{i}\sqrt{p_i}|\psi^{i}_{AB}\rangle)(\sum_{j}\sqrt{p_j}\langle\psi^{j}_{AB}|)\\
 &=  \sum_{i}p_i|\psi^{i}_{AB}\rangle\langle \psi^i_{AB}|+\sum_{i\neq j}\sqrt{p_ip_j}|\psi^{i}_{AB}\rangle\langle \psi^j_{AB}| \tag{2}
\end{align*}

clearly the above equation is not the same as the above definition.
I think I misunderstood the definition or equation 1. The actual definition only says that ${\displaystyle \rho =\sum _{j}p_{j}|\psi _{j}\rangle \langle \psi _{j}|}$ if we cannot write it as a bra-ket state. Since $|\psi_{AB}\rangle$ is pure, **I think equation 2 is correct and 1 is wrong.**

But the problem is if I try to apply trace over the states of $B$ for equation 2, I am not getting the correct $ \rho_{A}=\sum_{i}p_i|\psi^{i}_{A}\rangle\langle \psi^i_{A}|$ but I am getting this correct $ \rho_{A}$ if I take equation 1. With equation 2 I am getting
$$ \rho_{A}=\sum_{i}p_i|\psi^{i}_{A}\rangle\langle \psi^i_{A}| +\sum_{i\neq j}\sqrt{p_ip_j}|\psi^{i}_{A}\rangle\langle \psi^j_{A}| $$
Clearly this is wrong. I am using same notations as [arXiv:1805.11965](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11965). Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your equation (1) is not for a pure state. In other words, the statement in the first sentence is incorrect.

Comment: @RogerVadim I also said the same (read the bold sentence). But if I use equation 1 I am getting the correct answer for $\rho_{A}$ but not with equation 2.

Comment: Since, you have claimed $|\psi_{AB}\rangle $ is pure, it means you can transform to a different basis where you can write $|\psi_{ab}\rangle= |\phi_A\rangle |\phi_B\rangle$. So both eqn (2) and (1) are correct, provided such basis transformation exist

Comment: @KP99 I think even if we take any basis transformation the $\sum_{i\neq j}\sqrt{p_ip_j}|\psi^{i}_{AB}\rangle\langle \psi^j_{AB}|$ term will not become $0$.

Comment: @KasiReddySreemanReddy (1) is a mixed state, whereas the wave function before it is a pure state. They do not apply to the same situation, as your first sentence claims.

Comment: @RogerVadim Ok, my confusion is resolved now.

Comment: neither expression is "wrong", it's just that $|\psi_{AB}\rangle$ and the first expression you wrote for $\rho_{AB}$ do not represent the same state. As a simple example, try to apply this to $|0\rangle+|1\rangle$ and see how you get $I/2$ in one case and $|+\rangle\!\langle+|$ in the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think now my confusion is resolved.

> I think equation 2 is correct and 1 is wrong

This statement is true. But if I use equation 2 I will not get
$\rho_{A}=\sum_{i}p_i|\psi^{i}_{A}\rangle\langle \psi^i_{A}| +\sum_{i\neq j}\sqrt{p_ip_j}|\psi^{i}_{A}\rangle\langle \psi^j_{A}|$

The trace of $\rho_{AB}$ in  $\mathcal{H}_B$ is:
\begin{align*} 
&=\sum_k(\langle1_A|\otimes \langle\psi^{k}_{B}|)\rho_{AB}(|1_A\rangle\otimes |\psi^{k}_{B}\rangle)\\
&=\sum_k(\langle1_A|\otimes \langle\psi^{k}_{B}|)|\psi_{AB}\rangle\langle\psi_{AB}|(|1_A\rangle\otimes |\psi^{k}_{B}\rangle)\\
&=\sum_k\left(\langle1_A|\otimes \langle\psi^{k}_{B}|\left(\sum_{i}p_i|\psi^{i}_{AB}\rangle\langle \psi^i_{AB}|+\sum_{i\neq j}\sqrt{p_ip_j}|\psi^{i}_{AB}\rangle\langle \psi^j_{AB}|\right)|1_A\rangle\otimes |\psi^{k}_{B}\rangle\right)\\
&=\sum_k\left(\sum_{i}p_i|\psi^{i}_{A}\rangle\langle \psi^i_{A}|\delta_{ik}+\sum_{i\neq j}\sqrt{p_ip_j}|\psi^{i}_{A}\rangle\langle \psi^j_{A}|\delta_{ik}\delta_{jk}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i}p_i|\psi^{i}_{A}\rangle\langle \psi^i_{A}|+0
\end{align*}
The last term becomes $0$ because $\delta_{ik}\delta_{jk}$ is always $0$ if $i\neq j$. To get the last step we used $|\psi^{i}_{AB}\rangle=|\psi^{i}_{A}\rangle\otimes|\psi^{i}_{B}\rangle$.

Comment: Yeah, so I think there was an apparent confusion with the notation used in eqn (1) and (2). $p_i$ in (1) is just the probability of occurrence of state $\psi^i_{AB}$ in an ensemble, while $\sqrt{p_i}$ in eqn(2) is probability of state $\psi^i$(both A and B) wrt some observable.

Comment: I think it would be good not to use the same symbol $p$ for the probability of a state in a classical ensemble (which always can be modelled as arising from classical uncertainty), and amplitudes. Not doing this can lead to not appreciating how different superposition and classical mixtures are, while this is one of the key parts to understand about quantum mechanics imho. Of course there are situations where using $\sqrt{p} $ is justified (e.g. purification theorems), but then there's a clear distinction between the mixed state and associated pure state.

Comment: @KennethGoodenough OK I will use different symbols for them from now.